# How to include NodeCallback and MatrixTransform Library in visual studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, openscenegraph

I am using microsoft Visual Studio 2010, I receive an error when I include NodeCallback or MatrixTransform.

```
include <osg/NodeCallback>
include <osg/MatrixTransform>
```

the above two library are underlined with red which indicatesthat it has an error.

the following is the output from the visual studio when I build the file:

```
animationcallback.h(2): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'osg/NodeCallback': No such file or directory
```

So how can I remove these errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the OSG include folder as an include directory to your project.

```
Right-click on the project -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories.
```